# Limit MVC HTTP requests to particular endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC application (on IIS 7.5 in Azure) that exposes public and private (only within data centre) HTTP ports.  I would like to limit some requests to the private HTTP endpoint.  How can I determine the endpoint from within my request, or use routing, or any other mechanism.  I don't want to examine the URL for a port number because I believe this can be spoofed.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  What do you mean by "limit some requests"?  requests from what?  Do you mean you only want to accept requests from specific IP's?  How do you want them limited?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I want to reject requests that have not come via my private ("internal" in Azure-speak) endpoint/port.  I don't care about the remote IP.